# Arduino and N mosfet lithium battery charging/discharging measuring capacity

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, battery-charging, lithium-ion, discharge

[image]I need an Arduino based lithium battery tester that uses N channel Mosfets to switch On charging from and external power source and discharging through a 2 Ohm resistor. I have no issues with either charging or discharging circuit schematic, however i can not combine them together. I'm attaching the schematic for discharging the battery into the 2 Ohm resistor, please help with adding the components for making it able to charge the battery from an external, let's say 4.2V power source, all controlled by Arduino.

I also need to have a state when i'm Not charging or discharging so i guess for that purpose i need to use Pin 11 on Arduino

Comment: changed to an answer

Comment: I find your question and the follow-up a bit confusing. But I think your PFET, Q2, is backwards. When Q2 is off, that is supposed to disconnect the battery from a charger (not shown) connected to the high wire in your schematic, right? But it wont work because the body diode of Q2 will be forward biased. Connect the drain of Q2 to the battery and connect the source of Q2 to the regulated charger.

Comment: yes @mkeith he got the PFET backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Surely a high side PFET connecting the battery + terminal to the 4.2V external supply is enough. I hope you aren't doing anything unsafe, I really hope you've read about thermal issues, charge currents and voltage cycles with Lipo batties.

If you have the default logic state as the 4.2V thing connected to the battery, then have the system with a pull down resistor on Pin 12. Then when Pin 12 goes high, it will turn on the NFET low-side switch to provide the 2 Ohm load, and the gate voltage of the P fet will rise and turn it off, thus allowing you to test the battery without the 4.2V thing interfering.

You can swap the logic (not recommended, unless you also detach the battery when not in use) by putting a pull-up resistor on Pin 12 and driving it low to allow the battery to charge again.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, i tried before adding the P-fet, though it was getting hot and never went off. Could you please upload schematic. I have P channel TPCA8106 fet and N Channel TPC8028 fets. Also what should be the value for the pull-down resistor? I'm also uploading an updated schematic. Is it possible to attain the same goal with N channel fets only? cos i have many of those... thank you

Comment: I also need to have a state when i'm Not charging or discharging so i guess for that purpose i need to use Pin 11 on Arduino. Am i right?

Comment: See my comment above. I think your PFET was backwards. That is why it never turned off.

Comment: It does now. Thank you. Do i need to connect a pull up or pull down resistor for the P channel fet also?

Comment: in theory a pull-up will turn it off, but that turns ON the NFET if they use the same control lines. You can have two different digital pins of course, and have 00 (both off) 01 (maybe resistor on, charge off) , 10 (resistor off, charge on) and 11 (both features on). @Adrian

Comment: I had the P fet High charging OFF, and when i switched N fet to HIGH the battery started to discharge through R2 = 2 Ohm, but also the drain wire from P fet disoldered instantly... so i'm definitely doing something wrong. Could you please correct my schematic and post. I would highly highly appreciate that!!!

Comment: if the PFET gate (pulled up to source with resistor) and source are at 4.2V, the difference for Vgs is 0V and it should be totally "OFF". Turn off the PFET first before turning on the NFET, if you can, in software.

Comment: Also can you verify what voltages you are using @Adrian ? Is it actually 4.2V? I haven't searched those part numbers you have on your schematic, but do you know if they can actually turn fully on/off properly at only 4.2V?

Comment: @Adrian Your schematic is still a partial. What is connected to the other side of the PFET? You just show a nameless wire going off somewhere. Once the PFET is oriented correctly, the body diode can be forward biased if VBAT is > Vsource (source voltage of PFET). So if whatever is connected to Vsource can sink current, then it will forward bias the diode and drain the battery, even when the PFET is off. The PFET can prevent charge, but it cannot prevent discharge. You could add a second PFET in series, with diode facing the other way to get a complete disconnect, if needed.

Comment: Yeah, the sequencing is important. If the PFET and NFET are on at the same time, that is not a good thing. Although you do have the resistor to limit current.